Withdrawn window not reappearing with deiconify after filedialog in Tkinter on MacOS
The code below is meant to ask for a file name with filedialog with a hidden root window, after which the root reappears and shows a label that has the selected filename. However, on MacOS 14.5 and Python 3.9.6, the deiconify does not make the window reappear. I have to click on the Python icon in the dock in order for the window to appear. If I replace the filedialog line with file_name = '\example\file\name', no such issue occurs. How can I make the window appear without needing to click on the icon?
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, Label

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title="Select File")
if file_name:
    Label(root, text=file_name, padx=20, pady=20).pack()
    root.update()
    root.deiconify()
    root.mainloop()
else:
    root.destroy()

Edit: Interestingly, if I add cursor="cross" to the Label, the cursor does indeed change to a cross when hovering over the location in the screen where the window eventually appears. So it seems to be there somehow, and is just invisible.

Have you tried using root.iconify() instead of root.withdraw()? I think they behave differently on Mac vs. Windows, but I'm not on my Mac at the moment so I can't say for sure.

Yes, but unfortunately the same issue occurs.

Ah darn...I can try to look into this later

You can try to add root.attributes("-topmost", True) immediately followed by root.attributes("-topmost", False) or root.focus_set() or root.focus_force() or any combination of those. You can also try what they do in python's source code

I tried all of those separately before, and all in combination now, and the issue persists. I'm feeling stumped.

Does it help root.geometry()?

I tried it just before mainloop just now and made no difference

Try not creating root before calling askopenfilename() (one is created implicitly if parent is None).  Create root inside if block.

for this simple example you could destroy root before if file_name: and create new root = Tk() in if file_name:.

I also tried not passing a parent for askopenfilename() and  creating two instances of Tk() (even though it is discouraged). I tried reproducing this issue on another Mac and cannot, so this might be a machine-specific issue. Should I vote to close this thread?

Upgrading to Python 3.12 fixed the issue.
